# Wordpress how open menu in lightbox

Tags: html, wordpress, lightbox

How I can open a menu item of wordpress us a lightbox with inside a contact form (cf7).

I have tried to use: Lightbox 2 and Wp Lightbox and Responsive Lightbox,
and put the rel="lightbox" inside Relazioni tra link (XFN). When I click the page continued loading but doesn't open.

With Responsible Lightbox, after trying to load it tells me "Image cannot be loaded. Make sure the path is correct and image exists."

How I can do?
Thanks!

Comment: thank you @mhatch . Can you help me to fix my problem? i mean the Wordpress problem... or just you like fix the text?

Answer (score 1):

You can use fancy box like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
```

```html
<a id="inline" href="#main-menu">This shows content of element who has id="main-menu"</a>

<div style="display:none">
  <div id="main-menu">
      <?php
  wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'items_wrap'     => '<ul><li id="item-id"><?php __( 'Menu:',   'textdomain' ); ?></li>%3$s</ul>'
) );
       ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank @shoaib ! In the end i have use Fancybox for WordPress, inside have Jquery edit and was more easy to use, don't need write code in header and in this way i don't have make from zero all the menu! But thanks you have me show the way!